# How to solve the problem of using Socket to set up service to deny other computers under LAN?

Tags: node.js, sockets, vuejs2, electron, koa

My technology stack is Electron+Vue+koa+Socket+node. I built node service with Koa+socket on the server, and the front end used Vue. When I started the service on computer A, only computer A could successfully connect to the server, while computer B could not, and this error was reported:

```
GET http://192.168.1.114:9090/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MzPtclY net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

This is the client connection server code:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client'
let host = 'http://192.168.1.114:9090'
const socket = io.connect(host)
export default socket
```

This is the server code:

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const path = require('path');
const koaSend = require('koa-send');
const static = require('koa-static');
const socket = require('koa-socket');
const cors = require('koa2-cors')
const users = {}; 
const onlineUsers = [] 
const sockS = {}; 
const io = new socket({
    ioOptions: {
        pingTimeout: 10000,
        pingInterval: 5000
    }
});


const app = new Koa();

io.attach(app);
app.use(static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));


app.use(async(ctx, next) => {
    if (!/\./.test(ctx.request.url)) {
        await koaSend(
            ctx,
            'index.html', {
                root: path.join(__dirname, './'),
                maxage: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
                gzip: true,
            } // eslint-disable-line
        );
    } else {
        await next();
    }
});

app.use(cors());

app._io.on('connection', sock => {
    sock.on('join', data => {
        console.log('join', data)
        sock.join(data.roomid, () => {
            if (!users[data.roomid]) {
                users[data.roomid] = [];
            }
            let obj = {
                account: data.account,
                id: sock.id
            };
            let arr = users[data.roomid].filter(v => v.account === data.account);
            if (!arr.length) {
                users[data.roomid].push(obj);
                onlineUsers.push(data.account)
            }
            console.log(users, 'online:', onlineUsers)
            sockS[data.account] = sock;

            app._io.in(data.roomid).emit('joined', onlineUsers); 
        });
    });
    sock.on('logout', data => {
        console.log('user loggedout:', data.account)
        let arr = users['phone1V1']
        arr.splice(arr.findIndex(item => item.account === data.account), 1)
        onlineUsers.splice(onlineUsers.findIndex(item => item === data.account), 1)
        console.log(users, onlineUsers)
        app._io.in('phone1V1').emit('loggedOut', data.account); 
    })
    sock.on('offer', data => {
        console.log('offer', data);
        sock.to(data.roomid).emit('offer', data);
    });
    sock.on('answer', data => {
        console.log('answer', data);
        sock.to(data.roomid).emit('answer', data);
    });
    sock.on('__ice_candidate', data => {
        console.log('__ice_candidate', data);
        sock.to(data.roomid).emit('__ice_candidate', data);
    });
    // 1 v 1
    sock.on('apply', data => {
        console.log('apply', data);
        console.log('apply data:', data)
        sockS[data.account].emit('apply', data);
    });
    sock.on('reply', data => { 
        console.log('apply', data);

        sockS[data.account].emit('reply', data);
    });
    sock.on('1v1answer', data => { 
        console.log('1v1answer', data);

        sockS[data.account].emit('1v1answer', data);
    });
    sock.on('1v1ICE', data => { 
        console.log('1v1ICE', data);

        sockS[data.account].emit('1v1ICE', data);
    });
    sock.on('1v1offer', data => { 
        console.log('1v1offer', data);

        sockS[data.account].emit('1v1offer', data);
    });
    sock.on('1v1hangup', data => { 
        console.log('1v1hangup', data);

        sockS[data.account].emit('1v1hangup', data);
    });
});
app._io.on('disconnect', (sock) => {
    for (let k in users) {
        users[k] = users[k].filter(v => v.id !== sock.id);
    }
    console.log(`disconnect id => ${users}`);
});

let port = 9090;
app.listen(port, _ => {
    console.log('app started at port ...' + port);
});
```

Comment: What OS?  Windows has a local firewall that won't allow incoming connections from other systems without permission/configuration.

Comment: Your title doesn't agree with your question.

Comment: @jfriend00,windows 10.I tried to turn off the firewall, but it didn't work

Comment: Well, it seems likely that the Windows firewall is your issue.  There are lots of articles you can find with Google on configuring it or allowing an app like node.js to have incoming connections.